# Socket.bind() returns "The requested address is not valid in its context." on Win7

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-7

I am trying to use the Socket.bind() function this way:

```
Bind(new IPEndPoint(myInternalAddress, myPort));
```

The error I am getting is "The requested address is not valid in its context.", but this only happens on Windows 7 (I am using 64 bit).

Befor my upgrade a few days ago this was working fine, and I checked the IPs to be the correct ones.

Any help would be appreciated on what exactly goes wrong here.

Comment: myInternalAddress is my local IP (192.168.1.23) and myPort is 53532, but the port doesn't matter, as it didn't work for any of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bind()` ... binds a socket to local **IP address** and **port**. That's what `IPEndPoint` takes in its constructor (see [`IPEndPoint(address, port)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329633%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)). Looks like you are passing local and remote addresses there instead.

#### Edit:

If none of the ports work then it's probably the IP address that is wrong. Since you mention an "upgrade" - see what changed - is the address still the same? [`ipconfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450051.aspx) - hint, hint.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sadly, that was not the issue here, I just failed at copying the code.

Comment: Did the connection settings change? Like different DHCP server?

Comment: Yes. I changed my DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 (as my university's dns server is really unstable) and tried to connect to a local server using his local name... Thanks :)

Comment: migrated the app to a new server and forgot about that element of the configuration for the client.