# Socket.bind to all ips - An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to bind the socket to all the IP addresses available on the machine using:

```
  mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 0)); //or IPAddress.Any
```

but I get an `An invalid argument was supplied` on

```
 mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);
```

Instead, when I specify the IP, it works just fine.

[image]

Ok maybe that's impossible to achieve. But how about detecting which internet interface is being used to connect to internet and getting it's ip? (assuming user is behind NAT / router)

Comment: You need to specify IP address for EndPoint, as you are giving IP address with zero's it doesn't get the EndPoint because for binding socket with IP it need specific IP address and port.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146885/socket-bind-returns-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context-on-win

Comment: I do know that, but what about binding to all the ip's?

Comment: Use (new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port))

Comment: i have used that too, the same result. read carefully

Comment: Can you post full error here?

Comment: see my update (image attached)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3798/discussion-between-emaad-ali-and-develroot)

Comment: replace "ReceiveAll" by "ReceiveAllMulticast"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible.
Operation with sockets has limitations according to this document
[TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx)